# Java: StringBuffer & Concatenation

Tags: java, concatenation, stringbuffer

I'm using StringBuffer in Java to concat strings together, like so:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

str.append("string value");
```

I would like to know if there's a method (although I didn't find anything from a quick glance at the documentation) or some other way to add "padding".

Let me explain; every time I append something to the string, I want to add a space in the end, like so:

```
String foo = "string value";
str.append(foo + " ");
```

and I have several calls to append.. and every time, I want to add a space. Is there a way to set the object so that it will add a space automatically after each append?

EDIT --

```
String input
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.UseDelimiter("\n");

do {
   System.out.println("sql> ");

   input = scanner.next();

   if (!empty(input)) query.append(input);

   if (query.toString().trim().endsWith(";")) {
         //run query
   }
}
while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit");
```

I'll use StringBuilder though as grom suggested, but that's how the code looks right now

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java

Comment: can you show us some of your actual code where you are appending items? Because maybe there is another way of building the string that would make more sense.

Comment: hmm, I basically have a do-while loop that appends an input to a string and the loop exists when the input ends with a ";"

Comment: It's probably more elegant (and quicker) to use a regular expression to determine whether to run the query or not, e.g.: if (query.matches(".*;\s*")) {

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check input ends with ';' instead of converting the buffer to a string each time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is handled easier either with a helper method (untested code):

```
public String myMethod() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    addToBuffer(sb, "Hello").addToBuffer("there,");
    addToBuffer(sb, "it").addToBuffer(sb, "works");
}

private StringBuilder addToBuffer(StringBuilder sb, String what) {
    return sb.append(what).append(' ');  // char is even faster here! ;)
}
```

Or even using a Builder pattern with a fluent interface (also untested code):

```
public String myMethod() {
    SBBuilder builder = new SBBuilder()
        .add("Hello").add("there")
        .add("it", "works", "just", "fine!");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        builder.add("adding").add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    System.out.println(builder.build());
}

public static class SBBuilder {
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public SBBuilder add(String... parts) {
        for (String p : parts) {
            sb.append(p).append(' '); // char is even faster here! ;)
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String build() {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's an [article](http://java.dzone.com/news/factories-builders-and-fluent-) on the subject.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Let me know if you run into any kind of problems and I'll be glad to help! :)

Answer (score 6):

You should be using [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

> Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations.

Answer (score 4):

StringBuffer is final. You cannot derive from it.
The Best solution really is to add the padding for yourself. Write a method for it and use a  PADDING-Constant so that you can easily change it, or better put it in a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not create a new class which wraps around `StringBuffer` and add an `appendWithTrailingSpace()` method?

```
CustomStringBuffer str = new CustomStringBuffer();
str.appendWithTrailingSpace("string value");
```

(Although you may want to call your method something a little shorter.)

Comment: That should not be possible. StringBuffer is final, i.e. no derivation from it.

Comment: How does an incorrect answer get accepted and worse upvoted? Its not possible to subclass StringBuffer

Comment: Whoops.  You're right.  I've changed the answer to read "wraps around" rather than "extends".  Sadly it's not as neat this way.

Comment: I actually think that wrapping the string buffer is just fine.  Subclassing is not really appropriate in this case - you are really creating a 'builder' object using composition.  Nothing wrong with it, and if the decide later to use a different implementation you can...

Answer (score 2):

Just add the space yourself, it's easy enough, as per your own example.

Comment: yeah it's easy, but I find it dirty. And if I happen to change my mind and instead of a space, I want some other character, I'd have to go through several lines instead of one!

Comment: although yeah, I could do this: String bar = " "; str.append(foo + bar); but still I want to find out if there's a better way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that StringBuilder objects return themselves when you call append, meaning you can do:

```
str.append("string value").append(" ");
```

Not quite as slick, but it is probably an easier solution than the + " " method.

Another possibility is to build a wrapper class, like PaddedStringBuilder, that provides the same methods but applies the padding you want, since you can't inherit.