# Array List Output

Tags: java, arraylist, stringbuffer

I am currently using an Iterator to output an array list but I want to output it all on one line. I think my best bet would be to use a stringbuffer but does anyone have a more effective method?

My current method of output is this:

```
Iterator itr = cards.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(itr.next());
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Went with this Not efficient at all but its all I understand at the moment:

```
 Iterator itr = cards.iterator();
 String str = "";
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        str += (itr.next() + ", ");
    }
    return str;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

See [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays#toString` to convert an array into a `String`, like so:

```
final String string = Arrays.toString( myArray );
System.out.println( string );
```

- [`Arrays`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: So I am getting an error about this line. final String string = Array.toString(cards);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.out.print() method,  it doesn't change the line.

But I recommend to use a more efficient method, like the StringBuffer that you had suggest.

Comment: It is debatable if it is more efficient. Sure StringBuffer is more efficient in some situations (and no doubt more flexible in general), but this is not the case IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some search on stackoverflow. I think there are some good solutions for your problem. 
For example check this:
[Java: StringBuffer & Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152190/java-stringbuffer-concatenation)

You should solve the problem like this:

```
public String myMethod() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Iterator itr = cards.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        addToBuffer(sb, itr.next());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void addToBuffer(StringBuilder sb, String what) {
    sb.append(what).append(' ');  // char is even faster here! ;)
}
```