# append control + A character in string java

Tags: java, string

In java I have to place Control + A character to separate fields . So how can I append or concat Control + A character in StringBuffer using java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final char ctrlA = '\u0001';
```

happens to be unicode-16, char 1

edit: if you want a more 'automated' method you could use a StringBuilder as you are reading in the fields. someone already explained this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/152677/4197697

Comment: That's fine, is it not directly possible to append ctrl+A character at the time string creation without declaring character like this

Comment: '\u0001' is the Ctrl+A character, but declaring it like this makes your code readable

Comment: yes that's fine, but is there a way to append at the time of string creation

Comment: yea. using StringBuilder, see the link i added to the answer