# How to get data from Set in one go

Tags: java, collections, printing

I want to get all values of a set interface in one go as a comma separated string.

For Example(Java Language):

```
Set<String> fruits=  new HashSet<String>();

fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("Orange");
```

If I print the set as `fruits.toString` then the output would be:

```
[Apple, Banana, Orange]
```

But my requirement is `Apple, Banana, Orange` without the square brackets.

Comment: Homework?  You can try using String's substring() on the result of toString().  A better way would be to iterate over the Set and concatenate each element of the list with a StringBuilder.

Comment: When asking questions, please specify language & make it a part of the tag.

Comment: Can someone add a 'VB' tag to this? Or VBScript, whatever it might be.

Comment: Cant be VB. Uses semicolon & uses small toString. Makes it look like Java but Java doesn't have Set statement AFAIK

Comment: It's probably just Java, and the Set type (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: In any case, declaring a Set object called fruits and never using it indicates the code should at least be cleaned up a little.

Comment: Java has Sets it's an abstract class hence using a HashSet as the instance class. It's not C# as it doesn't have Sets (Damn them!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is Java.

MartinodF's quick and dirty `toString().substring` approach will work, but what you're really looking for is a `join` method. If you do a lot of string manipulation, I'd suggest you take a look at the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) [Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library. It provides a lot of useful features that are missing from the Java standard library, including a StringUtils class that would let you do this:

```
Set fruits =  new HashSet();

fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("Orange");

String allFruits = StringUtils.join(fruits, ", ");
// allFruits is now "Apple, Banana, Orange"
```

Comment: Not bad idea, but for above code I have to used commons-lang.jar file which is not acceptable in my case.

Comment: Because it's homework and he should have to figure it out himself?

Comment: I am a developer in my team therefore I can’t ask architecture team to use a new jar file for only these kinds of transformation. So finally I have made a generic method which will convert collection data to comma separated string, I asked this question because I thought some intelligent guys know some better and optimized solution.

Comment: Here is developed code:
private String collectionToCommaSeparatedString(Collection<String> value){

  Iterator<String> it = value.iterator();
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  while ( it.hasNext() == true )
  {
     result.append( it.next());
     if(it.hasNext())
      result.append(",");
  }
  return result.toString()  ;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
value.toString().substring(1, value.toString().length - 1);
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't see any reason this would fail. It would be much cleaner to iterate through the set, creating the string as you go, but this is good enough.

Comment: At least don't call toString twice.

Comment: I don't even know which language is that!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C# 3.5

```
var fruits = new HashSet<string>();

fruits.Add("Apple");
fruits.Add("Banana");
fruits.Add("Orange");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",fruits.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.util.Collection,%20char)) from commons lang

```
Set fruits =  new HashSet();

fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("Orange");


System.out.println(StringUtils.join(fruits, ','));
```