# Is there a direct equivalent in Java for Python's str.join?

Tags: java, python, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What’s the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)
>   [Java: convert List<String> to a join()d string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string)

In Java, given a collection, getting the iterator and doing a separate case for the first (or last) element and the rest to get a comma separated string seems quite dull, is there something like `str.join` in Python?

Extra clarification for avoiding it being closed as duplicate: I'd rather not use external libraries like Apache Commons.

Thanks!

### update a few years after...

[Java 8 came to the rescue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: See [What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java), and try one of the join methods from Apache [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Comment: Just write an utility to do that. Be careful the join should be done with StringBuffer or StringBuilder for hight performance.

Comment: Great question, I also found that whole missing-trailing separator problem very tedious for years ! Never knew about the str.join thing in Python - very useful shortcut! ... str.join(",",["thanks","very","much"]) ...

Comment: @monojohnny You don't need to use it as a class method, the first argument is the implicit *self*, so you can do `",".join(["thanks","very","much"])` instead :-)

Comment: @Wayne I think it's not worth the hassle xD

Comment: @fortran - even better cheers! (Albeit a little odd-looking if you didn't know what it was doing, in that way that ternary-ifs are until you get used to them...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a long time Java offered no such method. Like many others I did my versions of such join for array of strings and collections (iterators).

But Java 8 added `String.join()`:

```
String[] arr = { "ala", "ma", "kota" };
String joined = String.join(" ", arr);
System.out.println(joined);
```

Comment: With Java 8 `String` has a static `join()` method, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/1115554

Comment: added example of Java 8 `String.join()`

Answer (score 15):

Nope there is not. Here is my attempt:

```
/**
 * Join a collection of strings and add commas as delimiters.
 * @require words.size() > 0 && words != null
 */
public static String concatWithCommas(Collection<String> words) {
    StringBuilder wordList = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        wordList.append(word + ",");
    }
    return new String(wordList.deleteCharAt(wordList.length() - 1));
}
```

Comment: Correct. But it would be better if the method could take a Collection argument instead, so it works regardless of implementation.

Comment: And from force of habit, I was going to say it should take a `Collection<? extends String>`, but on second thoughts, don't bother. :-)

Comment: @Andrzej yeah, the first time I noticed that String was final I was really disappointed for all the dirty things that I couldn't do xD

Comment: You should add a second param that just takes a character and replace "," with it. I'd say you should provide a default argument but that requires you to write another method D:< One of Java's failings, IMO

Comment: Yeah I should make it more reusable.. but I can't be bothered now :) I could also do return wordList.substring(0, wordList.length() - 2) or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing in the standard library, but Guava for example has [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) that does this.

> ```
> Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(";").skipNulls();
> . . .
> return joiner.join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");
> // returns "Harry; Ron; Hermione"
> ```

You can always write your own using a [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), though.

Comment: I was under the impression that the same Apache library containing StringBuilder had a `join` function no? But its been a bit since I touched that code, so maybe I misremember...

Comment: @Petriborg: `java.lang.StringBuilder` is JavaSE, not Apache's. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: @Petriborg StringUtil of apache commmons has join (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29).

Answer (score 3):

A compromise solution between not writing extra "utils" code and not using external libraries that I've found is the following *two-liner*:

```
/* collection is an object that formats to something like "[1, 2, 3...]"
  (as the case of ArrayList, Set, etc.)
  That is part of the contract of the Collection interface.
*/
String res = collection.toString();
res = res.substring(1, res.length()-1);
```

Comment: I would be wary of using this - the `toString` output isn't guaranteed to have any specific format on `java.util.ArrayList`.  It's *unlikely* it would change but that would be entirely legal.  It would be safer (and arguably clearer) just to write the few lines of "extra utils code", IMHO.

Comment: The API specifies that `AbstractCollection`'s toString is formatted as bracketed comma separated strings: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Not in the standard library. It is in [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29) of [commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).