# Join comma if not empty or null

Tags: java

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)  answer of how to join String[] to comma separated string.

However I need the util to join the string in the array **only** if the values are not empty.

What is the best way to do it? without looping before on the String[] to remove. I prefer one method that does both.

**EDITED**

for instance:

```
I, love, , u
```

will be:

```
 I love u
```

Comment: How can you do that without a loop? Or do you mean without *you* making the loop?

Comment: Internally any Third party Utility you choose would be using loop

Comment: Have you tried StringUtils.join as mentioned in the linked question? It should also handle the case of an empty array somehow... if not you can always build an `if (givenStringArray.length > 0) { ... }` clause around it, right?

Comment: are you using a one dimensional array?

Comment: I mean the internal values, not the string itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class So20111214a {
    public static String join(String[] argStrings) {
        if (argStrings == null) {
            return "";
        }
        String ret = "";
        if (argStrings.length > 0) {
            ret = argStrings[0];
        } // if
        for (int i = 1; i<argStrings.length; i++) {
            ret += (argStrings[i] == null) 
                    ? "" 
                    : (argStrings[i].isEmpty() 
                        ? "" 
                        :  ( "," + argStrings[i] ) );
        } // for
        return ret;
    } // join() method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] grandmasters = {  
            "Emanuel Lasker", 
            "José Raúl Capablanca", 
            "Alexander Alekhine", 
            "Siegbert Tarrasch", 
            "Frank Marshall"  
        };
        String[] s1 = null;
        String[] s2 = {};
        String[] s3 = { "Mikhail Botvinnik" };
        System.out.println(join(s1));
        System.out.println(join(s2));
        System.out.println(join(s3));
        System.out.println(join(grandmasters));
        System.out.println(join(new String[]{"I", "love", "", null, "u!"}));
    } // main() method

    /* output:
    <empty string>
    <empty string>
    Mikhail Botvinnik
    Emanuel Lasker,José Raúl Capablanca,Alexander Alekhine,Siegbert Tarrasch,Frank Marshall
    I,love,u!
    */

} // So20111214a class
```

PS: Sorry for using the ? operator - I had to do it quickly, I am at work. :)

Comment: This works well as long as the first element of the array is not null or empty.  However, it would be easy enough to loop through elements to determine the first non-null/empty element and set the initial index of the second loop based on that index.

Answer (score 52):

In Java 8 you can use Stream:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("I", " ", "love", null, "you");
    String message = list.stream().filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.println("message = " + message);
```

Comment: The Stream can also be created by `Stream.of(T... values)`.

Comment: For Android, It requires, `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)`

Answer (score 9):

For Java 8 here is a solution using stream API .Filter null and empty Strings and join with a space between each string

```
String joined = Stream.of(I, love, , u)
      .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21998868)

Comment: Nobody cares about explaining words when [Brian Goetz makes the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36706013/2104560)

Answer (score 5):

For only null skip guava the best choice:

```
Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join("I", null, "love", null, "u")
```

Comment: What's the package of class Joiner?

Comment: It is from Guava librarry

Answer (score 5):

A pure Java 11 solution is:

```
String message = Stream.of("I", null, "Love", "     ", "You")
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(message);
```

> I Love You

If you really need to use array - then instead `Stream.of()` you can do:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[] { "I", null, "Love", "     ", "You" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Any problem with checking for null/empty?

```
String[] values = ?;
if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
  // join
}
```

The answer you pointed to already does the join using [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Your requirement doesn't quite fit with that, but it is so simple that it seems best to implement your own join loop, e.g.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String word: words) {
        if (word != null && (word = word.trim()).length() > 0) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(',');
            }
            sb.append(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I knew it but wanted to see if there is something already written

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't simply loop on array and use StringBuilder to build comma separated string for not null values only.

Answer (score 1):

Without any **API** or **library**, we could join *non-blank*, *not-null* string array as follows:

**User-defined method:**

```
public String joinNonBlankStringArray(String s[], String separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (s != null && s.length > 0) {
        for (String w : s) {
            if (w != null && !w.trim().isEmpty()) {
                sb.append(w);
                sb.append(separator);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);// length() - 1 to cut-down last extra separator
}
```

**Calling user-defined method:**

```
String s[] = {" ","abc", "", "XYZ", "      ", null, "123", null};
String joinVal = joinNonBlankStringArray(s, ",");// "abc,XYZ,123"
```

Answer (score -3):

Jakarta StringUtils does it.
Here is the code from there:

```
public static String join(Object[] array, String separator) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return join(array, separator, 0, array.length);
}
```

Comment: It checks if the string is null, but not if the values of the string[] are empty or null