# Detecting the first iteration through a for-each loop in Java

Tags: java, foreach

I'm working on a server that returns character separated lists to its client.
In order to build these lists I have to detect the first iteration through a for-each loop:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;
    boolean firstIterationFlag = true ;

    for ( String s : list ){
        if ( firstIterationFlag) {
            firstIterationFlag = false ;
        } else {
            builder.append(separator);
        }
        builder.append(s) ;         
   }
   return builder.toString() ;
```

Is there a way of doing this without the flag?

Comment: Why do you have to detect the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: instead of a `forEach` loop, you could manually do a normal `for` loop, starting with index `1` instead of 0.

Comment: Have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java - it may be a better solution that yours.

Comment: ...or user list.indexOf(s) to get index...

Comment: @vilo: that is potentially a linear-time hit to each iteration, so a O(n^2) hit to the routine just to glue some text together.

Comment: @andersoj: you're right. I didn't think about that. I thought it's about code polishing (small string collections). `org.apache.commons.StringUtils.join()` looks good.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One simpler way for this situation is to note that you can always append an empty string:

```
// For the first iteration, use a no-op separator
String currentSeparator = "";
for (String s : list) {
    builder.append(currentSeparator);
    builder.append(s);
    // From the second iteration onwards, use this
    currentSeparator = separator;
}
```

Alternatively (and preferrably) use Guava's [`Joiner`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class to start with :)

This "joiner" scenario is almost *always* the one given for this requirement - so just use `Joiner`. For other scenarios, either use a regular `for` loop or use the condition as per your code.

Comment: The ``if`` eliminated, but more difficult to grasp

Comment: I use StringUtils.join from Apache commons-lang.

Comment: @raviWallau so did I, before I knew Guava's Joiner :-)

Answer (score 9):

Not using foreach, but by using the iterator manually:

```
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
if(it.hasNext()){
    doSomeThingForTheFirstTime(it.next());
    while(it.hasNext()){
        doSomethingElse(it.next);
    }
}
```

(btw, this is pretty much what Guava's Joiner class does internally, though on a higher level)

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case you cite, use Guava's [Joiner](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) instead of rolling your own...

> An object which joins pieces of text (specified as an array, Iterable, varargs or even a Map) with a separator. It either appends the results to an Appendable or returns them as a String. Example:

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(separator).skipNulls();
return joiner.join(list);
```

Comment: +1 (Guava's Joiner is far superior to anything in apache commons)

Answer (score 3):

**Java 8 Solution**

If you have Java 8 available, you can simply use [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-), no need for Guava:

```
String.join(", ", list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun here is a different option.

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list) {
        builder.append(separator);
        builder.append(s);
    }
    builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :)

```
int i = 0;
for (something : manythings) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use commons.lang StringUtils.join function (see http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).  I strongly recommend that you get acquainted with this and other helper libraries to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following method:

```
public static String toString(List<?> list, String separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<?> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object next = it.next();
        sb.append(next);
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(separator);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

`#i` is an automatically generated identifier

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will not detect the first iteration in the loop, but solve the problem. Just append the seperator at the end of each string and cut off the last seperator.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;

for ( String s : list ) {
    builder.append(s) ;         
    builder.append(separator);
}
builder.setLength(builder.length() - separator.length());
return builder.toString() ;
```