# Inserting punctuation marks in a java String

Tags: java

Is there is custom way of inserting punctuation marks in a java String?

Lets say i have this small program:

```
class Punctuation Marks {
public static void main (String[]args) {

String Greetings="Hello how are you";

System.out.println("Greetings");
}
}
```

Intended output: Hello,how are you.

Comment: The question is too vogue.

Comment: There is no magical way that can add all punctuation marks at all appropriate positions in a sentence automatically for you.

Comment: @alfasin - your smelling is too amusing :-)

Comment: @StephenC Now not only I have BED spelling, but I also smell bad ? :D I meant vague obviously...

Comment: @alfasin obviously .......... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
String greetings = "Hello" + "," + " how are you";
```

Or this:

```
String greetings = "Hello how are you";
greetings = greetings.substring(0, 5) + "," + greetings.substring(5);
```

Or this:

```
String greetings = "Hello how are you";
greetings = new StringBuilder(greetings).insert(5, ",").toString();
```

Inserting a punctuation mark is trivial if you know *where* it should go. But if you don't know the exact place beforehand, it's impossible!

Comment: Ok let me make it clearer, what am actually doing in my program is print names of managers in a department. i want to be able to print each manager name with a comma

Comment: This is the method
    
    public String getManagers(){    
    String managers=new String();
    for (int i=0; i<numOfStaff;i++)
    if (employee[i].position.equalsIgnoreCase("manager")) {
    numOfManagers++;
    managers+= employee[i].employeeName+","; 
    } return managers;
    }

Comment: Sorry about the format of my code :(

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu - This is NOTHING to do with your original Question.  If you want an answer, I suggest you ask a new Question.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu - Actually, don't bother.  Read this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the punctuation at a given location is easy, just use `StringBuilder.insert(int index, char toInsert);` Programmaticly determining *where* the punctuation belongs, and what kind to use, is damn near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the answers is that automatic punctuation is nigh impossible.

Why?

Basically because there are a lot of sequences of words that could be punctuated in different ways to mean different things.  For example.

```
  the cow jumped over the hill I saw another cow
```

can be punctuated as

```
  The cow jumped.  Over the hill I saw another cow.
```

or

```
  The cow jumped over the hill.  I saw another cow.
```

which clearly mean different things.  (Can *you* tell me which is the right one?  Why?  And are you still correct if there are moles in the field?)

Basically, deciding which of the possible alternatives is the "correct" one requires deep understanding of what the punctuated utterances *mean* ... *in the context that they appear*.  This is most likely beyond the state of the art of natural language processing, and certainly not something that a run-of-the-mill application should attempt.