# How to delete only commas that appear because of Arrays.toString()

Tags: java, arrays, output, tostring

Replacing square brackets is not a problem, but the problem is with replacing commas,
**`replace(",", "")`** , because it does it with all commas in my **table** and i need to delete only those which appears because of  `Arrays.toString()`

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( product ).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", ""));
```

If there is no way of do that, maybe there are other ways to print my array, like string builder...etc? but i am not sure how to use it

Comment: If you don't like the output of `Arrays.toString()`, don't use it.  Instead, use a loop.

Comment: [What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

Comment: well the lopp does not work.Each time using it, instead of reasult i get [LProduct;@24de1f47
[LProduct;@24de1f47

Comment: Thats because you didnt override the toString() function in your objects class

Comment: how would Arrays.toString() work any better?

Comment: no, i use the  toString() function in my object class

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `Arrays.toString`, since you don't want the output it creates, use your own loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(400);
for (int i = 0; i < product.length; ++i) {
    sb.append(product[i].toString());
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Note I'm using `toString` on your `product` entries; there may be a more appropriate choice depending on what those are.

If you want a delimiter (other than `,`, obviously), just append it to the `StringBuilder` as you go:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(400);
for (int i = 0; i < product.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        sb.append(yourDelimiter);
    }
    sb.append(product[i].toString());
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

We dont know what your objects look like in your array, but you shouldnt use `Arrays.toString` if you dont like the output since its only a helper method to save you some time. Just iterate over your objects with a loop and print them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great library of apache where you can achieve your goal in one line of code:
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

```
String delimiter = " ";
StringUtils.join(array, delimiter);
```