# what's a simple and elegant way to print arraylist elements separated by comma?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Hi I'm writing code to print all elements from an ArrayList separated by comma, the folllowing is the method I wrote. It works. But i'm wondering if it can be simplified? And is there a more elegant way to print all elements from an ArrayList separated by some delimiter? (e.g. a method that prints an ArrayList of Strings get "Tom, Sherlock, Jack")

Thanks everyone!

```
public String printMyArrayList() {
    if(mylist.size() == 0)return "";
    else if(mylist.size() == 1)return mylist.get(0).toString();
    else {
        String returnStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size() ; i++) {
            if(i == 0)returnStr = mylist.get(i).toString();
            else {
                returnStr = returnStr + ", " + mylist.get(i).toString();
            }
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A quick and easy way to join array elements with a separator (the opposite of split) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp), and [What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

Comment: Remember to check if `mylist` is `null` before checking the size, it may produce a `NullPointerException` otherwise

Comment: @Ian2thedv and that is probably a good thing, because a list should never be null in the first place. Checking for null would hide a bug.

Comment: @KarolKrol: OP himself alternates between calling it *printing* and *joining*. The suggested (already working!) code is *called* `print..` but it doesn't really do that. Also: printing *could* be programmed in a different way than first joining and then printing, but there is no reason to.

Answer (score 9):

Using [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) from Java 8:

```
return list.stream()
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 4):

Another Java 8 solution using [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"});

String joined = String.join(", ", l);

System.out.println(joined);
```

Output:

```
foo, bar, baz
```

Comment: OP is using `item.toString()` which suggest that this is not List of Strings or other CharSequence so `String.join` can't be used here.

Comment: @Pshemo Sure, but that is not the point of the question. The joining is the intersting part, not converting objects to Strings.

Comment: I am not saying that tit is bad solution, but since OP seems to ask how to elegantly print list of *any elements* (not only `CharSequence`) I would say that mentioning that this solution will work only for types which can be used as `List<CharSequence>` `CharSequence[]` is quite important.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner.

`System.out.println(myArrayList.toString().replaceAll("\\[\\]", ""));`

I.e. get the default String representation (which is `[1, 2, 3]`) and remove the braces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String delimiter = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Item x : list) {
    sb.append(delimiter).append(x);
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

You can also use the [Joiner class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)

```
Joiner.on(",").join(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with android try this:

```
android.text.TextUtils.join(", ", listOfObjects);
```

else there's a util in spring framework.

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(listOfObjects);
```

Comment: Where is `TextUtils` from?

Comment: Which begs the question: how to elegantly implement TextUtils.join(), since it's not a standard class.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean by "simple and elegant", but I'll go with it.

EDIT: String.join is probably the best way

DOUBLE EDIT: Don't use this, as pointed out in the comments below.

```
public String printMyArrayList(ArrayList<String> list)
{
   String result = "";
   for(String s : list)
   {
      result += s + ", ";
   }
   return result.substring(0, result.length()-2);
}
```

Comment: That is quite inefficient: it produces a lot of temporary String instances.

Comment: I'll admit I should have put more thought on this one. I append the delimiter on each loop so I had to remove that last part. I'll leave this answer here as a "How not to do this" kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Use `List#toString` method. It will enclose with `[]`. If you don't want to include `[]` than you can substring it.

```
   String listStr= list.toString();
   String withoutSym= listStr.substring(1, listStr.length()-1);
```