# How do I join a String[] without a delimiter in Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, string

There are [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java) about how to join a `String[]` in Java 8 with a delimiter, but how should a `String[]` be joined *without* a delimiter?

For example, `{"a", "b", "c"}` becomes `"abc"`.

---

Note: I know how to write a small function for this myself, so please do not leave custom solutions. I am looking for a one-liner from the standard library.

Comment: Use [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) with delimiter `""`

Comment: Empty string?..

Comment: Use an empty string as the delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( String.join("", new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}) );
}}
```

Outputs: abc

The relevant part being `String.join("", arrayStrings);`

[Javadoc for String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I could have just used args as the string array... whatever.

Comment: Sure, let's edit it like that and see what the moderators think about it. :)

Comment: @PerLundberg I don't quite understand the comment: "See what the moderators think about it"? _Also_, per the edit, I used `new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}` to be explicit: to be clear from the example about what exactly was joined, and then I show the output below that would be achieved from it. Is the `new String[]{...}` syntax detracting from the answer?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that edits are peer-moderated if you have less than 2000 reputation. The edit I suggested was rejected, which is fine; it's actually a bit clearer like you have it right now. A colleague of mine suggested another approach today so I added this a separate answer for clarity (don't really want to post code samples as a comment)

Comment: @PerLundberg Oh! I think I understand now. I did not even notice my own comment that I left way back when, and it appears that you were responding to that. Sorry. In fact, now I wonder why I thought using `args` would have been advantageous, as that would only have made it less obvious what was happening. Anyway, I see now where  you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what has already been said, you can even do it as simple as this if you so prefer:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.join("", "a", "b", "c"));
    }
}
```

I.e. you don't even have to wrap it in an array; since `String.join` takes a `...` (variable argument), you can just specify any number of `String` arguments without explicitly wrapping them in an `String[]` object.

---

*Note*: the big disadvantage of the approach above is that it obscures the distinction between the delimiter and the delimited strings; @Aaron's answer is generally preferable. But anyhow, it deserves to be mentioned that you *can* actually write it like this also.